# Making superclass variables read-only to children in TCL OO

Tags: tcl, readonly, instance-variables, superclass

Let's I have a class foo, with a variable bar. Now... I want that if there is a class moo, which has class foo as a superclass, I want that any attempts to write to, or better yet, even refer directly to bar will be errored out. This could save situations when someone is using my code (which could be compiled to byte-code), to not override, by having one's own variable with the same name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TclOO simply does not support the concept. Classes are not security boundaries in TclOO, just as namespaces are not security boundaries in plain Tcl (TclOO objects are really just fancy namespaces). Tcl's security boundaries are between interpreters, and between the Tcl script level and the (usually) C implementation level. We're considering adding “private” instance variables for Tcl 8.7, but even those won't be truly private; their names will still be predictable if you know how (and they will be accessible from outside the class; that's important for when using the variable with third-party code such as Tk). To reiterate: ***classes are not security boundaries***.

If you have something that must be locked out of sight, it is easiest to implement it in C. You can plug in [methods implemented in C](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Method.htm) into TclOO (applying whatever controls you can think of) and those methods can use the (C level only) [metadata mechanism](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclLib/Class.htm#M6) to create instance-attached storage that they can use. All the callbacks are in place to do deletion correctly at the right time. Methods in C are not much more complicated than commands in C; the function callback signature is a little different and the usage is a bit more complicated (because there are other standard operations on methods such as copying them) but if you can do one, you can figure out how to do the other too.